# When UITableView Scrolling Returned Wrong IndexPath.Row Value

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, scroll, custom-cell

This is my codes;

```
    // MARK: - Table View Delegate && Data Source Methods
    // **************************************************

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let index = indexPath.row
    print(index)

    if index == 0 {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("HeaderCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

        cell.backgroundColor = ColorHelper.getCellBackgroundColor()

        return cell
    }
    else {
        if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("GradeCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as? GradeCell {
            cell.activeViewController = self;
            cell.gradeButton.tag = index
            cell.creditButton.tag = index
            cell.lessonNameTextField.tag = index
            cell.lessonNameTextField.delegate = self

            cell.backgroundColor = ColorHelper.getCellBackgroundColor()

            return cell
        }

        return UITableViewCell()
    }
}
```

I have 11 cells and someone are missing, When i scrolled table view index returns like this;

0-1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-0-1-2..

After reload process, my values are confused. Wrong value in wrong cell, how can i fix this ?

Comment: It sounds like `func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int`  return 9

Comment: Are you reloading your tableview while scrolling?

Comment: What is `return UITableViewCell()` supposed to do?

Comment: 1) func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int return 11, there is no problem. Last 1 or 2 rows has a problem. They are referenced 0 and 1 cells. 
2) No, i don't reload tableview, anyway reloading it self.
3) return UITableViewCell() because i must, otherwise function has an error.

Comment: Try setting a breakpoint in different lines of the `else` clause and see if it passes through the nested `if let` clause.

Comment: Also make sure you tag people to notify them when you comment back using the @ sign.

Comment: I try but nothing changed. IndexPath returns 0-1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-10-2-1-0

Answer (score 0):

Your problem could possible be how many cells you are returning. Especially, if you are having problems with the last  one or two. From what you said, it sounds like you have 11 cells, make sure you `return 12`. The cells in a `UITableView` always start counting with 0 being the first cell and 10 being that last cell, in your case.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section:Int) -> Int {

    return 12
}
```

Comment: This is not solution for my problem. Because, i want 1 header cell, 10 grade cell, this way i have 1 header cell, 11 grade cell and same problem doesn't solved. My problem is about cell referenced, not cell count or content or etc.